# Why use img[:,:,::-1] instead of img in plt.imshow() in python

Tags: python, list, python-imaging-library, slice, imshow

I know how to slice a list in python. But I have a confusion when I see the following codes:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('test.jpg')
img = np.array(img)
print(img.shape) # (204,204,3)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])
```

Both the last two lines can display the image correctly. But I wonder why **img[:,:,::-1]** as the **img** itself can display correctly. Is it just for fun or intentionally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are selecting everything from the first two dimensions and then reversing the order of the colors so switching RGB to BGR or visa versa.

Comment: While this has been marked as duplicate, there is a little more nuance here than just python slice notation.

For one, normal python arrays cannot accept a tuple as a slice, that is part of numpy.

Secondly it's not clear if it's the slice notation itself which is the question or if it's why the last axis has been reversed.  I imagine the image you're plotting is in greyscale, if you try it with a color image you will find the red and blue color channels have been reversed.

Comment: You are amazing! @Zev Thanks, now I understand!